# On the keyboard either iphone or ipad, when the user press the Next(Return) button

Tags: iphone

I have made the Return button, the Next button to be able to go to the next line (textfield). How can I capture that the Next button was pressed(first question)? Then set focus on the next textfield (second question)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the:

```
becomeFirstResponder
```

method in the

```
- textField:DidEndEditing
```

Of your UITextField delegate to set the next text field as the "first responder".  This will focus the input on whoever is the first responder.

Also set:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then use this to capture when a user clicks Return:

```
// this helps dismiss the keyboard then the "done" button is clicked
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    // Or [textField2 becomeFirstResponder]; to focus the next field
    return NO;  // return NO so that a newline doesnt get put in the next input (usually only happens if the next field is a textView not a textField
}
```

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.randomsequence.com/articles/adding-a-toolbar-with-next-previous-above-uitextfield-keyboard-iphone/) too to see it in action with a keyboard toolbar.

Comment: Is there a method that captures that the next button was pressed/clicked? Is textFieldShouldReturn that method? I am confused.

Comment: Exactly, that method is called when the user clicks return/next/done.  From there, call becomeFirstResponder on the textField you want to have focus next.  Or, if noine should get focus, call resignFirstResponder on the field that the focus was on when return was clicked.

Comment: Thank you chown, I was thinking return/next/done were all retrieve using an individual method, but I see they are all the same button, just what we decide to name it.

Comment: Anytime Neil.  Feel free to accept an answer if you felt it was useful.

Comment: chown, where should I place textfieldShouldReturn in my code? I placed it as a separate method, but if I place a breakpoint after pressing the next button, it never stops there?

Comment: Make sure to set the view controller as the text fields delegate:  textField.delegate = self, in your viewDidLoad method, or through the interface builder.